# Planilha do Excel com células ilegíveis ao filtrar

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, phpexcel

Estou criando uma planilha do `Excel` usando o `phpExcel()`. Ao colocar filtros, o resultado da célula `C3` e `C4` onde se encontra o subtotal `SUBTOTAL()` fica com a seguinte aparência:

**Sem filtro**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Com FIltro**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe porque isso acontece?
Já tentei mudar o arquivo para diversas codificiações, inclusive `UNICODE-UTF8`, `ISO` e `WINDOWS`.
Quando salvo o arquivo em `.xls` funciona, mas preciso que seja salvo em `.xlsx`

Answer (score 0):

Desculpe, amigo, mas você não foi muito claro ao apresentar o seu problema, dizendo qual o problema e o resultado esperado. Contudo, me avise se isso te ajuda de alguma forma:

A fórmula SUBTOTAL() é uma alternativa às fórmulas tradicionais como SOMA(), CONT.VALORES(), MÉDIA()... quando se quer efetuar operações em um intervalo com filtro. Como posso verificar, a sua fórmula de SYBTOTAL() está realizando uma operação de contar (indicado po '3' no primeiro argumento), assim, C3 vai contar todos os itens visíveis (não excluídos nos filtros) do intervalo selecionado. Deduzo ainda que a célila acima (C2), que não mudou seu valor em ambas as figuras, deve ter como fórmula `=CONT.VALORES(B7:B878)`. Resumindo temos que:

- Fórmula `SUBTOTAL(3;intervalo)` > contará os valores do `intervalo` visível. Valores ocultados por filtros são excluídos.
- Fórmula `CONT.VALORES(intervalo)` > contará os valores do `intervalo`, independente há linhas ocultadas por filtros.

NOTA: a fórmula SUBTOTAL() só diferencia-se em operações com intervalos afetados por filtros. Linhas e colunas ocultadas manualmente não terão seus valores excluídos de operações, retornando resultados idênticos a outras funções.

Comment: Olá, Julio, o problema que está ocorrendo é que quando eu filtro alguma coluna, os resultados das células C3 e C4 ficam ilegíveis, como na figura 2. O mais estranho é que quando eu redimensiono a colula, os valores (já com filtros) ficam legíveis. Isso só está acontecendo quando eu uso o PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excelObject,'Excel2007'); Se eu voltar para PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excelObject,'Excel5'); funciona normalmente, mas o Excel5 não possui os recursos que estou precisando. Entende?